# How to deploy WP app directly to phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there anyway to install wp application to the phone directly, Lets say I have a wp application and xap file, I want to put it somewhere on internet and the wp user will get that link and install application to the phone.
 **I dont want to put it to Marketplace and I dont want to deploy it to phone from PC**.
I want directly get it from internet and install to the machine.
Is that possible?

Comment: You'll need Zune client software and your phone device must be registered. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible.

Microsoft only wants deployments through the marketplace and for developers they created a way to deploy it from your pc to test stuff. for every other user all the installations have to go through the Marketplace.

The reason they do it this way is that they have control on which apps are being published for the platform and they will test all the applications submitted to the marketplace. If you could download apps while skipping the marketplace they can't do the testing etc.

Comment: hmm do you know what about Android?

Comment: In what way do i know something about Android? I know you have the apk files and you can just copy them to your phone and install them through an installer application. Windows Phone also doesn't allow you to use your phone as a file share so you can't copy xap files to the phone and then install them there. so there is really no way to do what you would want to do sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do beta-testing of your Application with a specified group of user
there is a special way. Its integrated within the marketplace, but your app wont be available to the public. Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334585%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Only developer unlocked phones can deploy XAP files in that manner. For others they have to download it from Marketplace, no other options are available.

But for hobbyists , there is  Chevron. This will allow you to side load apps .

You can can find several links explaining about ChevronWP7 over the internet.